# Diagnose crashes of FiftyOne app – logs or other tools

Tags: mlops, voxel51, fiftyone, image-annotations

We need to make a FiftyOne instance available to multiple users via a web browser.  We need to start a process and have it run, even after we log off from the session that initiated the app processes.

I’m using the following command to start the process.  I’m executing this in a Docker container.  The container is running on an Ubuntu host via AWS EC2.

```
$ nohup fiftyone app launch --remote > fiftyone.log 2>&1 &
```

If I launch this command from the terminal, it launches processes which allow a web browser to connect with the FiftyOne app.  These persists after I log out.

However, these processes sometimes become unavailable.  For example, after running for over 20 hours, FiftyOne crashed with the following in the log file `~/.fiftyone/var/lib/mongo/log/mongo.log`.

(produced by `cat ~/.fiftyone/var/lib/mongo/log/mongo.log | jq '{msg,t}'`)

```
{
  "msg": "CMD fsync",
  "t": {
    "$date": "2021-09-01T15:04:24.152+00:00"
  }
}
{
  "msg": "Received signal",
  "t": {
    "$date": "2021-09-01T15:04:24.181+00:00"
  }
}
{
  "msg": "Signal was sent by kill(2)",
  "t": {
    "$date": "2021-09-01T15:04:24.181+00:00"
  }
```

How might I get more information about why this crashed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The open-source version of FiftyOne is designed primarily for individual users. The best experience for multi-user collaboration is FiftyOne Teams. You can sign up here: https://voxel51.com/#teams-form

**About this error specifically**:

On the backend, calling `fiftyone app launch --remote` in effect runs the following Python commands:

```py
session = fo.launch_app(remote=True)
session.wait()
```

For remote sessions, the [`session.wait()`](https://voxel51.com/docs/fiftyone/api/fiftyone.core.session.html#fiftyone.core.session.Session.wait) call will block until something connects to it, and then will continue blocking until all connected tabs are closed.

There is a timeout built in to handle the case when the tab is refreshed so that the session is not immediately closed. In some cases, we have noticed that the refresh takes longer than the timeout, and sessions are closed prematurely. This is being looked into.

[The next release](https://github.com/voxel51/fiftyone/pull/1245) provides an argument that will cause `wait` to block indefinitely. You will be able to call `fiftyone app launch --remote --wait 0`.

In the meantime, I would recommend writing and calling a small script (`launch_app.py`) to permanently block until it is exited.

```py
import fiftyone as fo

session = fo.launch_app(remote=True)

# Indefinite blocking
while True:
    pass
```

```sh
python launch_app.py
```

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/14277626/eric-hofesmann, How will this work with ```nohup```?  We need the process to run, even when we destroy the terminal session.  Shall I create an infinite loop?

Comment: Good call! I have updated the answer to use an infinite loop instead of `input()`, thanks.